# Load Firebase asynchronously using RxJS or any other package - and then use it across the project

Tags: reactjs, firebase, webpack, rxjs, firebase-authentication

My question is not how to make it work, but how to make it right... I am experimenting with RxJS and not sure yet what is the best approach for that specific use case.

This approach was inspired by example repo, posted by Firebase team: [rxfire-samples - react](https://github.com/davideast/rxfire-samples/blob/master/src/react/index.tsx)

My goal is to use firebase in react application, lazy loaded with WebPack together with RxJS and I am planning to add redux-observable in the end.

At the moment I am loading firebase like this:

```
import { from, forkJoin, AsyncSubject } from 'rxjs'
import { tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { authListener } from '../auth/listener'

const CONFIG = {
 ...
}

const lazyLoadFireBase = (config) => {
    const app$ = from(import('firebase/app'))
    const firestore$ = from(import('firebase/firestore'))
    const fireAuth$ = from(import('firebase/auth'))

    return forkJoin(app$, firestore$, fireAuth$).pipe(
        map(([firebase]) => {
            const app = firebase.initializeApp(config)

            app.firestore().settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true })

            app.firestore().enablePersistence()

            return app
        })
    )
}

const firebaseApp = new AsyncSubject()

lazyLoadFireBase(CONFIG)
    .pipe(
        tap((app) => {
            authListener(app)
        })
    )
    .subscribe((app) => firebaseApp.next(app))

export { firebaseApp }
```

And if I want to use firebase doing something like this works, but it feels like not a right approach. I am wondering what would be a better way of sharing lazy-loaded Firebase package across the project.

```
import { firebaseApp } from '../../../store/firebase'

const logOut = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault()

    firebaseApp.subscribe((app) => {
        app.auth().signOut()
    })

}
```

---

Implemented changes suggested by @ggradnig:

```
import { from, forkJoin, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs'
import { tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { authListener } from '../auth/listener'

const CONFIG = {
}

const lazyLoadFireBase = (config) => {
    const app$ = from(import('firebase/app'))
    const firestore$ = from(import('firebase/firestore'))
    const fireAuth$ = from(import('firebase/auth'))

    return forkJoin(app$, firestore$, fireAuth$).pipe(
        map(([firebase]) => {
            const app = firebase.initializeApp(config)

            app.firestore().settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true })

            app.firestore().enablePersistence()

            return app
        })
    )
}

const firebaseApp = new ReplaySubject(1)

lazyLoadFireBase(CONFIG)
    .pipe(
        tap((app) => {
            authListener(app)
        })
    )
    .subscribe((app) => firebaseApp.next(app))

firebaseApp.asObservable()

export { firebaseApp }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two improvements I'd suggest. First, don't expose `Subject` or `AsyncSubject` to modules that only need to subscribe to it. Instead, you can use `firebaseApp.asObservable()` to get an object that only implements `Observable`.

Second, because of the exposure of the `Subject` signature, you are able to use `unsubscribe` in the other file, which you definitely shouldn't. Unsubscribing subjects will make them unusable for other subscribers. So, just remove the `unsubscribe` statement. [Ben Lesh even suggests not using `unsubscribe` at al](https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87)l.

Now, apart from these two style improvements, there may be a real trouble with your approach. `AsyncSubject` is used to encapsulate a single asynchronous operation. It has no caching mechanism, which means, you cannot subscribe multiple times on the same subject and receive the latest value. Subjects are always **hot**, so you have to subscribe before it emits. To work around that, you can use `ReplaySubject(1)`. It will cache the latest emission and replay it to all future subscribers.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I implemented your changes and it works nice.